# Конфликтует ajax форма и кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма и кнопки, которые отправляют данные, собсна.

При сабмите формы всё проходит нормально, а вот при нажатии любой кнопки - заодно отправляется форма.

Собственно, код:

```
function call() {

    preloader();

    var msg = $('#save_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://okop.ru/save.php',
        data: msg,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, str) {
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });

}

function paysrv(service, type) {
    var msgq = 'service=' + service + '&type=' + type;
    $('#pay' + type + 'conf').html('<img src = "http://cs.okop.ru/img/load.gif">');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://okop.ru/pyr.php',
        data: msgq,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#pay' + type + 'conf').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, str) {
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

Так вот, почему вместе с кнопками отправляется и форма? Функция от кнопок вызывается через onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если paysrv и call вызываются по нажатии на кнопки - добавьте в конец функции возврат false, например:

```
function paysrv(service, type){
  var msgq = 'service='+service+'&type='+type;
  $('#pay'+type+'conf').html('<img src = "http://cs.okop.ru/img/load.gif">');


  $.ajax({
`
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://okop.ru/pyr.php',
          data: msgq,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#pay'+type+'conf').html(data);
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });

    return false; //запретить сабмит с кнопки
}
```

Comment: e.preventDefault() — не даст сработать событию по-умолчанию. Например, если это применить к ссылке, то переход по ссылке не будет работать.

Comment: e.stopPropagation() — не дает событию «всплывать вверх» (как-то сложно перевести термин bubbling up с английского). Это значит, что отменит событие не только у элемента, но и у любого родительского элемента.

Comment: return false — то же самое, что вызвать два метода вместе.

Comment: см. http://olegorestov.ru/js/return_false_vs_preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

Для всех форм, которые нужно отправлять методом AJAX можно отменить стандартное действие:

```
$('form.ajaxForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```